# Send an array of JavaScript objects via POST

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, post, google-chrome-extension

I have an array of objects that I am trying to send to my PHP script. Before sending the array I can access all the data in it and everything is there. Once it gets to PHP var_dump returns NULL. I'm not quite sure how to send the data.

```
chrome.storage.local.get('object', function (object) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://example.com/php.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var uid = 2;

    JSON.stringify(object);
    xmlhttp.send("json=" + object + "&uid=" + uid);
});
```

The array:

```
var obj = [
    {
        "key": "val",
        "key2": "val2"
    },
    {
        "key": "val",
        "key2": "val2"
    }
]

obj.push({"key":val,"key2":val2});
chrome.storage.local.set({'object':obj});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
JSON.stringify(object);
```

does nothing useful: you're throwing away the returned value from `JSON.stringify()`. Instead:

```
object = JSON.stringify(object);
```

will keep it around.

You really should be encoding your parameters too:

```
xmlhttp.send("json=" + encodeURIComponent(object) + "&uid=" + encodeURIComponent(uid));
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I can't believe I didn't notice that.